# What's the proper way to expose the API and handle dependencies of DLL and adhere to SOLID?

Tags: c#, dll, dependency-injection, solid-principles

What's the best approach to expose the API of my distributable DLL and handle its dependencies, considering that these dependencies shouldn't be dealt by the clients but by the DLL itself, while still conforming to SOLID and other good practices (be testable, etc)?

The only way I could imagine being able to do this is by exposing a parameterless constructor using Poor Man's Injection with a static factory, like so:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService()
        : this(DependencyFactory.CreateObjectA(), DependencyFactory.CreateObjectB())
    {
    }

    internal MyService(IObjectA objectA, IObjectB objectB)
    {
    }
}

internal static class DependencyFactory
{
    internal static IObjectA CreateObjectA()
    {
        return new ObjectA();
    }

    internal static IObjectB CreateObjectB()
    {
        return new ObjectB();
    }
}
```

Is this the right path to take?

Comment: exposing an API or writing your own private code is almost the same thing (*according to the mainstream SO school of thoughts*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you keep a single public constructor for your components like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IObjectA objectA, IObjectB objectB)
    {
    }
}
```

And then create a default factory that clients of your library can use for convenience like this:

```
public static class MyConvenientFactory
{
    public static MyService CreateDefaultMyService()
    {
        return new MyService(new ObjectA(), new ObjectB());
    }
}
```

And the clients would create your components like this:

```
var service = MyConvenientFactory.CreateDefaultMyService();
```

Or a more advanced client will do something like this:

```
var service =
    new MyService(
        new CachingDecoratorForA(
            new ObjectA()),
        new LoggingDecoratorForB(
            new PerformanceRecorderForB(
                new ObjectB())));
```

Where `CachingDecoratorForA`, `LoggingDecoratorForB`, and `PerformanceRecorderForB` are decorators that are created by either you as the library provider or the client himself.

This allows the client to customize your component by composing differently. This is one of the benefits of applying the SOLID principles. See [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1295/object-composition-with-solid) for some discussion about object composition and SOLID.

If, for any reason, you don't want such an advanced client to customize your component via composition, then change the access modifier of the constructor to `internal` like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    internal MyService(IObjectA objectA, IObjectB objectB)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't new ObjectA() in the advanced client to be replaced by an IObjectA from a DependencyFactory.CreateObjectA() ?

Comment: You could provide a convenient factory for `ObjectA` or you could allow the client to construct it himself. Note that `ObjectA` might have dependencies and the advanced client might which to customize them as he did with `MyService`.

Comment: That's a great answer and article! It helped a lot and pointed me to the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, I posted an answer with my solution, take a look =) Oh, and marked yours as the accept answer, of course!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, thanks to Yacoub Massad's excellent answer and an article on [fluent builders](http://web.archive.org/web/20100421103639/http://stefanoricciardi.com:80/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/), I was able to implement a builder using the Builder pattern and the Decorator pattern with a fluent API. Here's how to use it:

```
var myService = MyServiceBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithCachingForA()
    .WithLoggingForB()
    .WithPerformanceRecorderForB()
    .Build();
```

The implementation:

```
public class MyServiceBuilder
{
    private IObjectA ObjectA;
    private IObjectB ObjectB;

    private MyServiceBuilder(IObjectA objectA, IObjectB objectB)
    {
        ObjectA = objectA;
        ObjectB = objectB;
    }

    public static MyServiceBuilder Create()
    {
        return new MyServiceBuilder(new ObjectA(), new ObjectB());
    }

    public MyServiceBuilder WithCachingForA()
    {
        ObjectA = new CachingDecoratorForA(ObjectA);
        return this;
    }

    public MyServiceBuilder WithLoggingForB()
    {
        ObjectB = new LoggingDecoratorForB(ObjectB);
        return this;
    }

    public MyServiceBuilder WithPerformanceRecorderForB()
    {
        ObjectB = new PerformanceRecorderForB(ObjectB);
        return this;
    }

    public MyService Build()
    {
        return new MyService(ObjectA, ObjectB);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is also meant for the simple client. The advanced client would still like to be able to compose at will.

Comment: Yes, this is meant for the simple client, to cover my need of hiding the ObjectA and ObjectB dependencies. If we were to let an advanced client customize these dependencies as well, we could then tweak it, maybe adding another static constructor like `public static MyServiceBuilder Create(IObjectA objectA, IObjectB objectB)`, or even better, with a new builder method like `public MyServiceBuilder WithCustomObjectA(IObjectA objectA)`.